# Поиск сообщений в Telegram за определенный промежуток времени по ключу

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, telethon

Мне нужно собрать по определенному ключу сообщения за последний месяц. Использую библиотеку telethon. Но при добавлении временного диапазона(offset_date + reverse=True) не работает поиск по ключу (search=''). Без reverse=True все работает. Но мне нужно получить сообщения только за последний месяц, поэтому выбираю смещение от определенной даты и реверсирую. Как решить проблему?

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from datetime import date


api_id = my_id
api_hash = ''
phone = ''

client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
dateStart = date(2022, 12, 27)


async def main():
    async for message in client.iter_messages(-1001369370434, reverse=True, offset_date=dateStart, search='eth'):
        print(message.chat.title, ':', message.date, ':', message.text)

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async for message in client.iter_messages(-1001369370434, search='eth', reverse=True, offset_date=dateStart):
```

Попробуйте местами аргументы переставить. Судя по документации telethon в этом может быть проблема

Comment: Пробовал менять все, не помогает. Читал api, для работы reverse=True, нужны аргументы entity= и ids=. Не могу понять что это

Comment: Хм, тогда можно попробовать вот это [из документации](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/search.html)

If either search, filter or from_user are provided, messages.Search will be used instead of messages.getHistory.

Comment: Так а куда это применить?